# Resize img element inside div without affecting div size

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to create a header for a website. My problem is, that I try to scale a img inside my div, but the div element resizes with it.

*This is my header*

[image]

I wish to keep the original size of the div (the green part), while being able to resize my cake img

Here is my current css for the header:

```
.container-header {
 position:inherit;
 vertical-align: top;
 background: green;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 300px;

}

.container-header img {
display:run-in;
height: 200px;
}

.container-header a {
display: inline-block;
background: red;
width: 100px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
}

.header-logo {
position: relative;
top: 100px;
}
```

Edit:
Here is my html:

```
<div class="container-header">

<a href="index.html" style="left: 25%"><p>Koti</p></a>
<a href="leipomot.html"><p>Leipomot</p></a>

<img class="header-logo" src="IMG\logo_placeholder.png" alt="" height="30px">

<a href="index.html"><p>Tuotteet</p></a>
<a href="yhteystiedot.html"><p>Yhteystiedot</p></a>

<a href="PHP/shoppingcart.php"><div class="shoppingcart">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi can you also post your html please so we can help. I would say if you set a max height then you can use overflow hidden to hide any additional image from showing, or better yet use a background image with background-size: cover and it will always fit without changing the div size.

Comment: How are you trying to "scale the image"?

Comment: You can probably set the header to a flex element, and your image container to `height: 1px; overflow: visible;` to allow the header children to flex, while having the image spill out of the container without resizing the green container.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `display:run-in;`. You can use `display:block` and `position: absolute` on the image, plus parameters for its position (top/bottom/left/right, also using percentage values), maybe `transform` (for centering), and size to position it wherever you want, independently of the parent element.

Comment: Actually there IS `display:run-in` but it's experimental - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: okay - I am always thinking of real-world websites which work *now*, sorry...

Comment: This worked for me, however I think this is kind of a messy way of doing this. I need to manually move most of the elements in order to make way for my image to be in the middle.

Comment: you could leave the original (small) image as is and *add* another, larger version of it, absolutely positioned and covering the smaller one. This should avoid the problems you describe.